# How can i change android app's firebase account as my account?

Tags: android, database, firebase

I have cloned the android project and it already connects the tutor's firebase account. So I need to connect it to my firebase account. Is it possible to do that? if it is possible how can I change cloned code and go for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! you can do that,
but before starting don't forget to change the package name of the app!!
refer this if you don't know how to change that [how to change app package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)
and then completing that go to your firebase console then create a new app and register the app with new package name and do the other steps required and then you will get config file, download that and replace the original `google-services.json` where it is located in the `app` directory (root folder) and replace with the one you downloaded from firebase! and that's it you are done

Answer (score 1):

Replace the original `google-services.json` with your `google-services.json` that's it.